# How to decode base64 encoded query params in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, base64

I am using Django Rest Framework quite extensively.

The version I am on now is v3.7.7

I am researching on how to handle query params when they exceed the 2000 character limit and I found this suggestion about using base64 encoding.

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/353105/16777

I like to know how to use Django Rest Framework's native code to handle the base64 encoding of the query params if possible.

**Update:**

the base64 encoding suggestion in the SWE stackexchange is a way to shorten the query params. It may still exceed the 2000 character limit in the URL.

If the shortened query param is using base64 encoding, how to do that within the Django Rest Framework way of working to decode the query param string?

**2nd Update:**

Thanks to @Daniel Roseman pointing this out in the comments, I just realized I was confused by the software engineering stack exchange answer. It would appear that base64 encoding increases the payload size.

In that case, my question would be more about how to decode base64 query params within Django Rest Framework, should that be needed?

Comment: That answer doesn't say that base64-encoding will allow query params longer than 2000 characters. On the contrary, that encoding will always *increase* the length. If you need longer parameters, use a method with a body (eg POST or PUT).

Comment: ah ... i have rephrased my question. yes i agree the base64encoded string might still be too long. ANd yes if still too long, i will have to use body with POST. I was wondering if i use base64 to encode the query params as suggested, how might the decoding be done within the DRF paradigm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your updated question is still wrong. b64 will never shorten parameters, it will always lengthen them.

However, if you did need this for some other reason, the way to do it would be to write a [custom parser](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/) and add it to the DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES setting.

Comment: Right, thanks! Yes, I now realize i was mistaken abut the shortening part. and now i am curious about how to decode base64 param string regardless. Thanks for the answer.